# How to better structure if statement in php?

Tags: php

```
<?php
function example($role) {   
  if($role == var1]) {
    return true;
  } else if(isset($var2) && !empty($var2)) {
    if($role == $var2) {
      return true;
    } else if(isset($var3) && !empty($var3)) {
      if($role == $var3){
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } 
  } 
}
```

`$var1`,`$var2`,`$var3` are session variables. `$var1` is always set so I check it directly in if statement.

`$var2`, `$var3` are not set sometimes so I added another if statement to check if `$var2` and `$var3` are set.

Basically I have to check a parameter of a function with respect to `$var1`, `$var2`, `$var3` and if parameter is equal to any of variable, the function should return value true.

Because `$var2` and `$var3` are not always set so I have to check `isset()` and not empty too for them. I am new at `PHP` and I can't form if statement correctly.

Problem with the function is that if `$var2` is not set, it won't check for `$var3`.

I want that the parameter is checked for `$var1` and if any of `$var2`and `$var3` are set, parameter should be checked with respect to them too.

Comment: What do you mean by `$var2 is not set`? Do you take it from some superglobal, like `$_SESSION` or `$_POST`?

Comment: $var1, $var2, $var3 are session varaibles

Answer (score 0):

Use one conditional with or's and group the parts that must match together. Something like:

```
function example($role){    
    if($role == $var1 || (!empty($var2) && $role == $var2) || (!empty($var3) && $role == $var3)) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

should do it. You also don't need to check `!empty` and `isset`, if it isn't empty than it is set. (exceptions are with the 5 values `empty` considers empty)

I'd also consider restructuring the data here. If you store all the `$var#`s in an array you could just use http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php.

Answer (score 0):

Since most of your conditions will return `true` you can style your code and group everything like this:

```
<?php
function example($role) {   
    if(
        (isset($var1) && !empty($var1) && $role == $var1) ||
        (isset($var2) && !empty($var2) && $role == $var2) ||
        (isset($var3) && !empty($var3) && $role == $var3)
    )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can maybe pass your variables directly in the function and make something like :
function example($role, $var1=null,$var2=null,$var3=null){  ... }

and then check if null or not